# Getting two ellipses instead of one

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have a code that needs to draw a circle, on random position, and also it needs to stay in predefined borders. In my code, I'm supposed to draw only one circle. In some cases, it draws only one but in other cases, it draws two of them and I have no idea why. 
[image: Click for photo]

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Random r = new Random();

    int leftX = 20;
    int topY = 60;
    int width = this.Width - (3 * leftX);
    int height = this.Height - (int)(2.5 * topY);

    float x = r.Next(20, width - 100);
    float y = r.Next(60, height - 100);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 100, 100);
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), rect); //rectangle around ellipse
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 3), leftX, topY, width, height); //border rectangle

    g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), rect);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `Form1_Paint()` gets called twice?

Comment: It can't be. I'm testing some stuff, as I said I'm trying to generate two random circles, on random positions. It's only this function in my project

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint at the beginning of your function to check it? Why can't it be? Oh wait, you're *trying to generate **two** random circles*? Then what's wrong with your image?

Comment: Try to resize the form. What you see?

Comment: @Rafalon Two random circles but my code stands only for one 
#Sinatr When I get two random circles and I resize, there're parts of the second circle, mostly pie

Comment: To understand the issue better move form out of screen and then back. Your form will receive multiple `Paint` events, but will only update small region (this is how winapi optimize redraw). And for each event (unless they arrive too fast, then random is initialized with same seed) you calculate new random `x` and `y`.

Comment: Not __the__ issue, just a mistake: Do not repeatedly create a new Random object. This is one source of unpredictability, as, they tend to deliver the same numbers, when created within a very short timespan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paint event gets called whenever the [form is re-drawn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx), so from your point of view, that's unpredictable.  You would be better moving the code to generate the position into the load event:

```
float x;
float y;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    x = r.Next(20, width - 100);
    y = r.Next(60, height - 100);

}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    int leftX = 20;
    int topY = 60;
    int width = this.Width - (3 * leftX);
    int height = this.Height - (int)(2.5 * topY);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 100, 100);
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), rect); //rectangle around ellipse
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 3), leftX, topY, width, height); //border rectangle

    g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), rect);
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Can you explain me how is this _unpredictable_?

Comment: @AnthinoRusso Paint happens whenever the form thinks it needs to redraw itself, this can be for many reasons, thus 'unpredictable'

Comment: Whenever Windows detects a situation where it thinks the display should be "refreshed", it will produce a message. This message may ultimately make it to your form, resulting in the `Paint` callback firing. Your code should always "paint" your graphics in their entirety and it cannot make any assumptions about the "canvas". In other words, you should always start with a clean slate.

Comment: Check this out if you are interested in more detail: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx